# Removing a specific line in bash with an exact string

Tags: sed

I'm having trouble in getting sed to remove just the specific line I want. Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
testfile
testfile.txt
testfile2
```

Currently I'm using this to remove the line I want:

```
sed -i "/$1/d" file
```

The issue is that with this if I were to give testfile as input it would delete all three lines but I want it to only remove the first line. How do I do this?

Comment: The command removes already all three lines.

Comment: `I want it to only remove the first line` based on what condition? Match whole line only, match only at the end, etc? Also, do you want to treat the input as regexp or a string? For example, if you pass `t..tf..e` should the first line be deleted or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So match the whole line.

```
var=testfile
sed -i '/^'"$var"'$/d' file
# or with " quoting
sed -i "/^$var\$/d" file
```

You can learn regex with fun online with regex crosswords.

Answer (score 3):

With grep

```sh
grep -x -F -v -- "$1" file
# or
grep -xFv -- "$1" file
```

`-F` is for "fixed strings" -- turns off regex engine.
`-x` is to match entire line.
`-v` is for "everything but" the matched line(s).
`--` to signal the end of options, in case $1 starts with a hyphen.

To save the file

```sh
grep -xFv -- "$1" file | sponge file     # `moreutils` package

# or
tmp=$(mktemp)
grep -xFv -- "$1" file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```